# Sort array of objects by one object's value

Tags: javascript

For example I have this array:

```
array = [
  {id : 0, name : "alex"},
  {id : 2, name : "mark"},
  {id : 1, name : "sarah"}
]
```

I want to sort this array to be in order depending on the `id` value.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: I already checked this post and it is not same.

Comment: You are looking to sort array of objects based on a property in that object. Right?

Comment: The answers on this question are more legit for this specific problem than answers on the one you linked even if the question is very similar. In any other case it is duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` function to sort the array.

**Note**: Your array is incorrect,it need be `{id : 0, name : "alex"}`.It should be `colon(:)` but not `equal(=)`

```
array = [
          {id : 0, name : "alex"},
          {id : 2, name : "mark"},
          {id : 1, name : "sarah"}
        ]
        var sortedArray =array.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.id-b.id; // for ascending order

        });
        console.log(sortedArray)
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yot75gpg/2/)

Documentation: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).`

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't careful when I was writing a question, I fixed it now. Can you provide documentation link for `sort` method so people can check browser support and other information when they are searching for a solution for their problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?, you can use .sort() function

```js
var array = [
  {id : 0, name : "alex"},
  {id : 2, name : "mark"},
  {id : 1, name : "sarah"}
]

var sortedArray = array.sort(function(obj, obj2){
  return obj.id - obj2.id
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(sortedArray,1,1) + "</pre>");
```